# Can two $n$-dimensional vectors that are not scalar multiples of each other be added to make any point on an $n$-dimensional coordinate plan?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, real-numbers, coordinate-systems

If we have $\pmb{u}, \pmb{v} \in \mathbb{R} ^ n$ and $c\pmb{u} \ne \pmb{v}$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then is

$\forall_{a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}} \left (\exists_{m, n \in \mathbb{R}} \left (m\pmb{u} + n\pmb{v} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a_1 \\
        \vdots \\
        a_n \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\right ) \right ) \text{ true?}$

Note: Bolded letters represent vectors.

Comment: if $n=2, $ yes, but if $\mathbf u=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, then no combination of $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ will give $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Since $dim(\mathbb{R^n}) = n$, any set of less than n vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ does not span $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: @JG123 Could you put that in an answer?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the counterexample!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\mathbb{R^n}$ has a basis of $n$ vectors (such as the standard unit basis {$e_1, e_2,.... e_n$}). By a known theorem from linear algebra, we then have that any set of less than $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$  does not span $\mathbb{R^n}$. Hence, as long as $n > 2$, vectors $u$ and $v$ could not span $\mathbb{R^n}$. That is, $\exists$ $a_1...a_n$ such that $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{R}$, $mu + nv \neq (a_1...a_n)$, which means the given statement cannot be true.

Answer (score 1):

The linear span of two vectors can never be more than a plane.